# There are too many active WebGL contexts on this page, the oldest context will be lost. [dedup.min.js]

Tags: angularjs, safari, webgl

I am getting this wiered error only on Safari browser. Don't know why. 
I am using AngularJS 1.3.x. 
[image: click here for image]

So how do I detect which libraries may be using this. 
And why only in safari I get this error ? 
Is there a way via JS to enable or disable WebGL ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your HTML?

```
<script>
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (function(origFn) {
  var bannedTypes = {
    "webgl": true,
    "webgl2": true,
    "experimental-webgl":, true,
  };
  return function() {
    var type = arguments[0];
    return bannedTypes[type]
       ? null
       : origFn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext));
</script>
```

As long as this appears before any other scripts it should block webgl.

The script above changes replaces the function `someCanvas.getContext` so that when some other JavaScript tries to create a "webgl" context it returns `null` which means creating the context fails. Otherwise if JavaScript asks for a different kind of context it calls the original `getContext` function.

As long as this script is executed first it should prevent other JavaScript on the page from creating a webgl context. It won't prevent JavaScript in iframes from creating contexts. You'd need to add the same solution to each iframe.

Comment: Well its working !! I understand what this script is doing, but can you elaborate as how did you come up with this solution and why ?