# Warning: "Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost" (WebGLRenderer.js)

Tags: webgl, autodesk-viewer

In Autodesk Forge Viewer I cannot instantiate more than 6 viewers (Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication) on the same page.

I've tried a solution proposed here which doesn't work:
[There are too many active WebGL contexts on this page, the oldest context will be lost. [dedup.min.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464621/there-are-too-many-active-webgl-contexts-on-this-page-the-oldest-context-will-b)

The function I use:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
                this.viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication(this.div_id);
                this.viewerApp.registerViewer(this.viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, { extensions: ['PropertyInspectorExtension']});
                this.viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
            }.bind(this));
```

Apparently, there is a way* to do it with Three.js but is it somehow implemented in Autodesk Forge ? Otherwise I don't know how to do it myself.

*Answers:
[Display multiple instances of three.js in a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959538/display-multiple-instances-of-three-js-in-a-single-page)
[Is it possible to enable unbounded number of renderers in THREE.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608723/is-it-possible-to-enable-unbounded-number-of-renderers-in-three-js)

*Example of result:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html

Comment: It is not implemented in Autodesk Forge Viewer. Maybe you could consider designing your page so only one view is active at a time. You could also try using [virtual-webgl](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl). You should probably disable webgl2 like it mentions in the readme.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of a workaround, but you could use this command line switch with Chrome:

`--max-active-webgl-contexts=<number>`

Of course this will only fix it *for you* and not anyone else, but sometimes that's enough.